# fetching the column value of 0 throws null value

Tags: php

In my db table, i have a column name `gender`, 0 - male and 1 - female. default value is 0.

when i tried by the following code, it doesnt goes well with the result.

```
male - 0 
female - 1
default value is 0



$gender =  $row['gender'] ? $row['gender'] : null;
```

instead of getting 0, i am getting null value. how can i solve this issue.

Am i wrong in seting the default value as 0, suppose if 0 has been kept, how can i solve he issue.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, a value of 0 evaluates as false when used in the context of a boolean as your conditional ternary operator does.

You need to be more explicit in your conditional.

For Example:

```
$gender = isset($row['gender']) ? $row['gender'] : null;
```